# How to use transform:translateX to move a child element horizontally 100% across the parent

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

All,

I'd like to be able to use `translateX` to animate a child element 100% of the way across it's parent (i.e., from the left edge to the right edge).

The challenge is that percentages in `translateX` refer to the element itself, not the parent.

So, for example, if my html looks like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
</div>
```

And my CSS like this (vendor-prefixes omitted):

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

This doesn't work - the child only moves 20px (100% of itself), not all the way across the parent. (You can see this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nA355/7/)):

[image]

I can do this:

```
#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px) translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(300px) translateX(-100%);
}
```

This works (seen  [here again on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nA355/7/)), because it first moves the child 300px (the full width of the parent), minus 20px (the width of the child). However, this depends on the parent having a fixed, known pixel dimension.

[image]

However, in my responsive design - I don't know the width of the parent, and it will change.

I know that I can use `left:0` and `right:0`, but the animation performance of left/right is much worse than translateX ([Thanks Paul Irish!](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way that I can think of would be having a wrapper around the child, with width = 100%, and animate it instead of the child

Comment: @vals Animating the `width` would probably suffer the same performance pitfalls as animating `left`, no?

Comment: @MurraySmith Correct, margin/width/left aren't GPU accelerated and will hurt performance. Go for transforms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the recent addition of [Size Container Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) it is now possible to do this by setting the `container-type` property to `inline-size` in the parent and then translating the child element by 100cqw - 100% where 100cqw is the full width of the parent and 100% is the width of the child.

```css
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    
    container-type: inline-size;
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    transform: translateX(calc(100cqw - 100%));
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer in 2023. Thank you.

Comment: The best answer in 2023 IF you do not need support for even marginally old browser versions, still a great answer, but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 39):

I didn't post my idea originally, because it involves creating an additional HTML layer, and expected better solutions to come.

Since that hasn't happened, I explain my comment. What I meant was this:

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#wrapper:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
#wrapper:hover #child {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Since the wrapper is 100% width of the parent, translating it 100% works as expected.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nprs7/)

Note that the wrapper is being translated 100% as you stated. However, seems that what you really want is to move  the element 100% - width. To achieve this, you have to translate the child also 100% (now this applies to the child width) in the opposite direction.

Correction: the child should share the transition property of the wrapper:

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    transition: all 5s;
}
#wrapper:hover {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    transition: inherit;
}
#wrapper:hover #child {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vals - this is a ***really*** clever solution. I added a transition on the child, so by the time the wrapper is 100% to the right, the child has moved 100% to the left. (See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nprs7/1/). It works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Great solution! But to avoid that awkward moving out of the parent at the beginning of the transition, you may want to add a delay to the child transition in order to be always inside the parent.

Comment: @gigaDIE Good point, I didn't noticed that problem in my original answer. Solved making the child inherit the transition property (see snippet)

Comment: Great, but still has a bug, the animation hangs while `#child` is hovered. You need to specify `:hover` on the `#parent` to avoid all the issues: http://jsfiddle.net/Nprs7/65/

Comment: I love this tip

Comment: I'd probably add `pointer-events: none;` to the wrapper and then `pointer-events: auto;` to the child to prevent overlapping issues.

Comment: The animation in the fiddle is quite jittery, though

Answer (score 15):

There's a pretty cool solution to this problem using Flexbox. The key is to take advantage of the *flex-grow* property.

Say you have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-spacer"></div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

First, give .flex-container the basic *display: flex* property, and set its *flex-direction* to *row*. Set the positioning of the child elements to *relative*, so they will sit next to each other inside .flex-container.

By default, the *flex-grow* property is set to *0*, which is exactly what we want at the beginning. This means that .flex-spacer and .slider will only have their normal dimensions to begin with. We simply keep .flex-spacer empty, and it will have a *width* of *0*.

Now for the animation. We only need two CSS rules to make it work: add a *transition* to .flex-spacer and set *flex-grow* to *1* on .flex-spacer during some event. The second rule gives all of the unused *width* inside .flex-container to the *width* of .flex-spacer, and the first rule animates the change in width. The .slider element gets pushed along to the edge of .flex-container.

The CSS looks something like this - I added a background to .flex-spacer to make its presence a little more obvious, and set *flex-grow* to *1* when the user hovers over .flex-container:

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.flex-spacer,
.slider {
  flex-grow: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.slider {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #0DD;
}

.flex-spacer {
  background-color: #DDD;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.flex-container:hover .flex-spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-spacer"></div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Flexbox makes this pretty configurable, too. For example, say we want .slider to move from right to left, instead. All we have to do is switch the *flex-direction* property in .flex-container to *row-reverse*, and we're done!

Feel free to play with it in this [pen](https://codepen.io/bradylambert/pen/wdbxwK).

Keep in mind that things can get a little trickier if we want animations for different types of events. For example, I came across this issue when trying to animate a label when a user types in an input element. A little more HTML and CSS is needed to make it work (I used some JS, as well), but the concept is the same.

Here's another [pen](https://codepen.io/bradylambert/pen/gWyBRJ), this time in the context of a form with input.

Comment: The problem with this is that it triggers paint flashing, so it's not really smooth/efficient.

Comment: This sadly doesn't work on IE11 as IE11 apparently doesn't animate flex-grow.

Comment: Good solution when sliders' width is variable, for example it's custom text.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this using wrapper and flex-grow:1.
Here are two animations at the same time with the same duration: 1) the container (green) moves with the car at 100% of the parent's width; 2) the car moves back -100% of its width (to stay on the track at the finish line). The duration can be taken separately and distributed to the container (.track-inner) and the car (.car)

```js
 const goBtn = document.querySelector('.go');
    const inner = document.querySelector('.track-inner');
    const car = document.querySelector('.car');
    const durationFromServerMS = '3000ms'; 
    
    goBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      inner.classList.add('drive');
      inner.style.animationDuration = durationFromServerMS;
      car.classList.add('backShift');
      car.style.animationDuration = durationFromServerMS;
    })
    
    const backBtn = document.querySelector('.back');
    backBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      inner.classList.remove('drive');
      car.classList.remove('backShift');
    })
```

```css
html, body {
      padding: 2rem;
    }
    
    .track{
      width: 50%;
      display:flex;
      position: relative;
      background-color: gray;
      width: auto;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      border: 5px dashed blue;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
    
    .track-inner{
      width: 100%;
      border: 5px dotted green; 
    }
    
    .car{
      width: 3rem;
      height: 1.5rem;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: salmon;
    }
    
    .finish-line{
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      right: 0.5rem;
      width: 3rem;
      height: 1.5rem;
      border-left: 6px dotted yellow;
    }
    
    button{
      padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
      background-color: lightblue;
      outline: none;
      border:none;
      margin: 0.2rem
    }
    
    button:hover{
      pointer:cursor;
      background-color: salmon;
    }
    
    
    .backShift {
      animation-name: car-back;
      /* animation-duration: 5s; */
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    .drive {
      animation-name: driving;
      /* animation-duration: 5s; */
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    
    @keyframes driving {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes car-back {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
    }
    
    p{
      padding:0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="track">
        <div class="track-inner">
          <div class="car ">car</div>
        </div>
        <div class="finish-line">finish</div>
      </div>
    
    <div>
      <button class='go'>Go</button>
      <button class='back'>Back</button>
    </div>
```