# Float image from left to right with a animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have a hamburger (three horizontal bars) icon I want to change from `float: left` to `float:right` but with a smooth animation.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ps1ZBDT.png?1]

I can't use jQuery but I can use JavaScript so I have this small function that changes float state when the image is clicked:

```
var menuButton = document.getElementById('menu-button');


menuButton.onclick = function () {

    menuButton.style.float =  "right";
}
```

So this works but not smooth animation how can I make it a smooth animation?

A running demo:

```js
var menuButton = document.getElementById('menu-button');


menuButton.onclick = function () {

    menuButton.style.float =  "right";
}
```

```css
   nav {
        background: pink;
        height: 60px;
    }

    nav #menu-button {
        margin: 20px 24px;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
    <nav id="nav-bar">
        <a href="#/index"><img id="menu-button"alt="menu icon" src="images/toggle-open.svg"></a>
    </nav>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar: The second sentence literally starts with "I can't use jQuery"

Comment: My eyes are deceiving me!!! @MadaraUchiha!!! LoL.

Comment: I think you would have to approach it by using a custom setInterval tweening function on a property such as `left` or `marginLeft`. CSS as far as I know cannot support float transitions smoothly.

Comment: this should help https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, changing left-to-right float can't be simply animated with any current tech, because an animation requires a relative anchor-point from which to perform calculations.

What you could do is animate the relative left-floated position, to an approximated right-floated position (by increasing left-margin, for example), and upon completion, change to a right-float.  But really, the last step isn't necessary, except to handle future layout changes to the page (e.g. window resize, for a fluid-width site).

I was able to get this working using CSS3 transitions and marginLeft.

There's a little hackery in the parentElement.parentElement (to climb two levels of the DOM tree), and in the -44px to account for the icon width plus margin width, but if you wanted to, you could write more complex coded solutions to these (handling the element's actual width / margin on the fly).

```js
var menuButton = document.getElementById('menu-button');
menuButton.onclick = function () {
    var left = menuButton.parentElement.parentElement.clientWidth - 44;
    menuButton.style.marginLeft =  left+"px";
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        menuButton.style.float =  "right";
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
nav {
    background: pink;
    height: 60px;
}

nav #menu-button {
    margin: 20px 24px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;

    /* Width and height hack to represent missing image's height and width */
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    /* CSS Transition added */
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
    <a href="#/index"><img id="menu-button"alt="menu icon" src="images/toggle-open.svg"></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks Steve this is kinda working, before I accept your answer, I just need to keep the margin of left-right 24px, I think I need to adjust a bit more, what is `parentElement.parentElement.clientWidth`  actually doing?

Comment: @Jessi - I made some adjustments to account for the margin already.  `parentElement.parentElement.clientWidth` gets the width of the `<nav>` element.  Take that - rightMargin - imageWidth, and you have the appropriate left margin to position your image at.  The correct value is 44, which I've updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: thanks a lot let me adjust and brb to accept your answer!

Comment: @Jessi - I made a final edit to add the right-float switch-over after the animation is complete.  I did this using `window.setTimeout`.  Now, when you resize the window, the menu will maintain its proper right-floated position.  You can test this by running the snippet above, and when it's complete, click the "Full screen" button and watch the nav stay right-floated.

Comment: thanks working great I replace -24 with `    var menuButtonWidth = menuButton.clientWidth;` so now if it changes I don't have to change in two parts, accepted your answer :D

Answer (score 4):

If you know the width of your  container, do not use `float` properties but `margin-left` :

```
a {
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
}
a.right{
  margin-left: 400px; /* change for good value */
}
```

Then add `right` class to your `a` element with javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/rd4h4s5h/

Answer (score 0):

I would  do it this way:

```
<style>
nav {
    position: relative;
}

nav a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: left 1s linear;
}
</style>



<nav id="nav-bar">
    <a id="box" href="#/index"><img id="menu-button" alt="menu icon" src="images/toggle-open.svg"></a>
</nav>



<script>
    const navBar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
    const box = document.getElementById("box");
    const menuButton = document.getElementById("menu-button")

    menuButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
       box.style.left = (navBar.offsetWidth - box.offsetWidth) + "px";
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution now, you could go a different way, achieving EXACTLY what you were trying to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75443310/3936149

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;

}

.contact-us-hero-btn {
    border-radius: 27px;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0px;
    background: #2f2f2f;
    padding: 8px !important;
    position:relative;
    container-type: inline-size;
}

.contact-us-hero-btn:hover .contact-us-circle {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-right {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100cqw - 100%));
        transform: translateX(calc(100cqw - 100%));
    }
}
@keyframes slide-right {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100cqw - 100%));
        transform: translateX(calc(100cqw - 100%));
    }
}

.contact-us-hero-btn svg {
    fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary mt-5 py-2 contact-us-hero-btn text-white" data-action="scroll-to-contact" listener="true">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="27" height="27" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-circle-fill contact-us-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                          <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8"></circle>
                                        </svg>

                                  </button>
```