# TranslateX a child div inside of a 100% width parent

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to make some jQuery fun on my website, the idea is that when you scroll down the page the parent div grows to be 100% width for responsive design, and works great, and at the same time I want to `translateX` the child div and stay always at the right edge of the parent for the animation and for different viewport sizes, only way I can make this work is with `float: left;` and `addClass` of `right: 0;`. It works, but it just jumps to the right. Is there a way to animate this?

I found this, but it does not solve my problem because the parent has an exact pixel width:

[How to use transform:translateX to move a child element horizontally 100% across the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557476/how-to-use-transformtranslatex-to-move-a-child-element-horizontally-100-across)

```
<div class = "parent">
    <div class = "child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    float: left;
    transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.moveParent {
    width: 100%;
}

.moveChild {
    right: 0px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(wScroll > $('.parent').offset().top){
        $('.parent').addClass('moveParent');
        $('child').addClass('moveChild');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS transitions have to change **from** something **to** something else, so it won't work if you just say `right: 0;`. For the animation to work correctly, you'll need to set a default right value.
Change your css to look like this:

**CSS**

```
.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    right: calc(100% - 180px);
    transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}
```

This will align the div to the left initially by calculating right: 100% - your div's width (180px). Then after the hover, it will animate to the right with `right: 0;`.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/459dzsyc/)

Comment: Is working perfect, just what i wanted, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Float isn't an animatable property in CSS**, so even though you set the transition to "all", as soon as you add the class, the effect will apply and it won't animate.
[Read More](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

You might want to experiment with starting at `left: 0` and animate that.

Here's a working fiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mew93o2/)

Comment: The reason your fiddle is working is because the `.parent` container is being animated and the `.child` is just aligning right while it grows to 100%. Even if you just said `right: 0;` your fiddle would work. As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/3mew93o2/1/