# Stack customized windows(divs) using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a single page application where you're suppose to be able to open multiple customized windows on the page(not browser tabs/windows, but windows created with DOM). I want the windows to stack on top of each-other with a certain XY-offset. I've tried added a `transform: translate(5%, 5%)`to the divs after the first div, but it simply isn't working.

I want them to stack like this:

[image]

But right now, they´re just stacking on top of each other.

HTML:

```
<main>
    <div class=window><div class=app></div></div>
    <div class=window><div class=app></div></div>
    <div class=window><div class=app></div></div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.window {
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to be able to help you.

Comment: can you keep track on the number of modals opened? if yes then you can keep incrementing the counter and then you can apply css like translate((counter+5)%, (counter+5)%)

Comment: please give some basic info about the html/css of your parent element and child div's. its important to know for example position absolute ... properties you used for them to understand your issue

Comment: If you found the answer to your own question, don't edit it into the question. Just give it as an answer yourself.

Comment: Okay, I will! Instead of fumbling with finding a rule for CSS, I made a solution with Javascript instead. Increased every newly opened divs top and left with 10px.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `position: absolute` to all the divs and use `left: <num>px` and `top: <num>px` to position them. Make sure the containing element is `position: relative`, otherwise the divs will be absolutely positioned relative to the "viewport".

See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) for more on absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this works with some caveats: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNbqgE

html:

```
<div class="card">1</div>
<div class="card">2</div>
<div class="card">3</div>
<div class="card">4</div>
<div class="card">5</div>
```

css:

```
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid #cc0000;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ddd;
}

.card:nth-of-type(n + 1) {
  transform: translate(5%, 5%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  transform: translate(10%, 10%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(n + 3) {
  transform: translate(15%, 15%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(n + 4) {
  transform: translate(20%, 20%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(n + 5) {
  transform: translate(25%, 25%);
}
```

The caveat is that you have to define a new nth-of-type rule for each level of card you need. If you're using less, sass, or other css build tool you can pretty easily setup a macro to generate any number of these.

Comment: Well, that kinda does it! Although, I will have to find a way to define a nth-of-type rule. The whole app is written in CSS, so may be to late to change all that to sass or less(unless you can import sass to css???). Any idea how to make a rule for each window?

Comment: I like your style. I prefer writing everything in standard css too. Build tools are useful but I still prefer writing everything out by hand. Just a tip, but the term "window" is confusing. Generally "window" refers to the browser, not DOM components. Sass/less etc are all just build tools built on top of css, so you can just dump your entire css project in with no changes. That being set, not necessary. If you know some average of "windows" you'll be using, you can just copy/paste and create the extras and modify n + (n) and the percents in the translate.

Comment: `.card:nth-of-type(n + 1)` should be `.card:nth-of-type(1)` in this code.

Answer (score 0):

`transform: translate(...)` applies to the element itself, not to the parent, so maybe that's the case it doesn't work for you. I would use a similar approach like the one mentioned by Jason Cemra. Check out this another answer, maybe it helps you: [How to use transform:translateX to move a child element horizontally 100% across the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557476/how-to-use-transformtranslatex-to-move-a-child-element-horizontally-100-across)

Answer (score 0):

to position of window div's, we have to set x-y position relative to a known reference. if all win div's are in a same parent, we have use different offset for them: eg: `transform: translate(5%, 5%);` for first div, `transform: translate(10%, 10%);` for second div, and so on.

another way is to nest them in each other such that the same value of offset can be used for all divs, but as their parent have different position, they get desired position:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0;
}

.window {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    border:1px solid navy;

    transform: translate(5%, 5%); /* this is relative to current position */
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div id=main>
    <div class=window><div class=app>w1</div>
        <div class=window><div class=app>w2</div>
            <div class=window><div class=app>w3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```